# How to have realtime many to many two way references in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-design, nosql

I have a user collection in **firestore** and each user object has an array of references to "tasks" that they have applied to. Tasks is a separate collection as well and each task object has a user ref array as well.

```
Collection Tasks: 
doc: {
   name: "Do something",
   time: "Time",
   users: ["/users/u1", "/users/u2"]
}

Collection Users: 
doc: {
    name: Username,
    tasks: [ "/tasks/docRef", "/tasks/anotherDoc" ]
}
```

I have a screen in my **react-native app** that lists all the tasks and when a task is clicked, it goes to a `details screen` that displays all the users in a list as well.

Is this the best approach to have this kind of data? Or should I have collections instead of arrays with references. I refrained from collections to prevent duplication of data but I'm not sure if they will be more efficient.

Comment: "I have an onSnapshot listener on the user and task document." Do you have a listener on EACH document (i.e. the user AND the task)? Note that by default the two docs in the two collections aren't linked at all

Comment: Yes, I have one on both

Comment: Can you explain the exact flow of operations. When you write "when a task is clicked, it goes to a details screen that displays all the users in a list as well." I understand that there isn't any write to the Firestore DB. If yes, which writes(s)?

Comment: Also when you write "When the task doc is changed, all the changes except the users array reflect in the application." Can you share the code corresponding to this action. (Please update your question by using the "edit" link)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Actually the not being sync was not the problem, I wanted to inquire if this was the right approach to store the data? Or should I just use u-ids and then query the collection to matching those ids? Or create a sub-collection in the user document itself with references to the tasks? Sorry, if it was not clear from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (From the comments )I wanted to inquire if this was the right approach to store the data?

> 1/ Should I just use uids and then query the collection to matching
> those ids?

Storing uid or `DocumentReference`s in the arrays will not make a difference in terms of ease of querying the corresponding documents. It would only make a difference at the level of the size of the document containing this data since DocumentReference`s are longer than uids).

> 2/ Or create a sub-collection in the user document itself with references to the tasks?

In the NoSQL world you should not hesitate to denormalize your data.

So having the `tasks` list in a `user` doc AND having the `users` list in a `task` doc and synchronize the docs when a change is done in one of the collections is a valid approach.

HOWEVER, you may encounter a problem if you have "a lot" of tasks for a given user or a lot of users involved in a task since you may hit the maximum size for a document which is  1 MiB (I agree that you need a LOT of tasks or users :-)).

To avoid that I would advise using sub-collections. This is also the preferred approach if you plan a high frequency of changes that could cause database contention or higher latency, see the [documentation section](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#updates_to_a_single_document) about "Designing for scale".

---

If the user data you want to show in a task is limited (e.g. just their name plus a button to open each user Profile based on the uid) I would keep an array of users in the task document with this limited amount of data (of course after being sure that there is no risk that a doc reaches the limit of 1 MiB). And have a sub-collection of task documents under each user doc (as advised above).

Comment: Actually there is a lot of fields in the data, so I think having sub-collections for both in each document would be the best approach right?

Comment: Do you need to display ALL the users data when displaying a Task?

Comment: I need to display all the users but not all user data, only the name and avatar at once

Comment: So using an Array of users in a Task seems to be the way to go (again, unless a Task has thousands of users attached)

Answer (score 2):

Modeling well in firestore is a bit difficult, you have to think hard about your use case.

Don't worry about data duplication, this is very common in Firestore. Remembering that you mainly pay for the number of reads and writes.

In your user array, you could keep the necessary data to save you from doing more reads on the user collection.

In your example, the user only has the username, you could keep the username and uid, saved in tasks. That way, no reads would be done on the user collection.

What if the user changes username? Use a [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) and update all docs that contain that user.

Comment: Actually in the real example, the user has a lot of fields and if I were to keep it in the tasks document should I use an array or a sub-collection?

Comment: It depends on your case, I understood the following.

You enter the tasks screen, click on a task, at that moment the users related to that task appear, what exactly does that user appear? If it's just a name and an image, you can keep an array of objects.

Comment: @Renaud said a very useful thing, document size, but I imagine you're not going to have thousands of users related to a task, correct?

Comment: I don't imagine thousands of users as this is an app for employer and employee task management but I do need to be able to query all the users for each specific task

Comment: This is possible, but in the query you will have to query for the object and not for the object's field.
So it would be a good idea to have an array containing only the userUid. This way you would do: ```tasksRef.where('userUids', 'array-contains','someId').get()```